# How to make every single part of a complex geometry thinner?

Tags: modeling, hair, photorealism

I got a CT-scanned **DICOM** images of a luffa (loofah) and I got a 3D version of it using a software called InVesalius (quite similar to 3D Slicer and you can export the geometry in various formats such as **.stl**, **.obj**, **.x3d**). I want to setup a CFD simulation of this luffa. The problem is, it is impossible to get a proper realistic (thin, hair-like) geometry of this luffa using both aforementioned software.

How do I do that in Blender using the exported 3D geometries? (I couldn't find anything searching & surfing the internet).

**Here is how it looks like in real life:**
[image]

---

**And here are how the 3D geometries I exported from InVesalius (or 3D Slicer) look in Blender:**
[image]

[image]

---

**Close up:**

[image]

How could I get a hair-like, thin geometry of a natural luffa in this virtual reconstruction?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you might be able to go about doing this, though they aren't going to provide you perfect results. Both of these techniques involve moving all faces in along their normals.

**Option 1**
In edit mode, select everything and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then slowly draw your mouse down to shrink. You may wish to select the Offset Even checkbox in the little settings box.

**Option 2**
Add a displace modifier to your mesh. Leave the Midlevel at 0.5, and set the strength to 0.0. Then, slowly draw the strength into the negative numbers, which will shrink the mesh. The exact number will depend heavily on the scale of your mesh, and the degree to which you need it thinned.

Comment: Thank you. These options didn't work for the geometry above. Thanks again, I appreciate it.